# Submit twice in jquery ot php?

Tags: php, jquery

Hi I have a form  in php which has a action and it goes to itself thus produces the results to the user which is what I want, however I want the user to have the option to click a button which will then go to the thank-you.php page which sends the information off to a admin.

I have been thinking about it but perhaps im over complicating it by having one form in another?

This is my form so far:

```
<?php
$data = array("Benalmadena"=>10,"Fuengirola"=>20,"Mijas"=>30,"La Cala"=>10,"Calahonda"=>15,
"Marbella"=>20,"Puerto Banus"=>25,"San Pedro"=>30,"Estepona"=>40, "Nerja"=>12);


error_reporting(E_ALL);

if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['to'])){

ini_set('date.timezone', 'Europe/Madrid');
$now = date("H:i");

$cutoff = "06:00";
$higherthan = "22:00";


$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$telephone = $_REQUEST['telephone'];
$from = $_REQUEST['from'];
$to = $_REQUEST['to'];
$date = $_REQUEST['date'];
$returndate = $_REQUEST['returndate'];
$people = $_REQUEST['people'];
$return = $_REQUEST['return'];
$myemail = $_REQUEST['myemail'];

include_once('includes/config.php');

$settingsSql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM transfers_in WHERE location='$to' AND no_passengers='$people'");
$settings        = mysql_fetch_assoc($settingsSql);

echo "From: ".$from." To: ".$settings['location']."<br />";
echo "Number of passengers: ".$settings['no_passengers']."<br />";

ini_set('date.timezone', 'Europe/Madrid');
$now = date("H:i");

$cutoff = "06:00";
$higherthan = "22:00";

echo "Time cost: ".$settings['price']." euros<br /><hr />Total: ";



    function timeCost() {

        $to = $_REQUEST['to'];
        $people = $_REQUEST['people'];
        $return = $_REQUEST['return'];

        include_once('includes/config.php');

        $settingsSql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM transfers_in WHERE location='$to' AND no_passengers='$people'");
        $settings        = mysql_fetch_assoc($settingsSql);

        //echo $return;

        if ($return == "No"){
            if ((strtotime($now) < strtotime($cutoff)) || (strtotime($now) > strtotime($higherthan))){
                return number_format($settings['price']) + 1.40;
            } else {
                return number_format($settings['price']) + 0.00;
            }
        } elseif ($return == "Yes") {
            if ((strtotime($now) < strtotime($cutoff)) || (strtotime($now) > strtotime($higherthan))){
                return number_format($settings['price']) * 2 + 1.40;
            } else {
                return number_format($settings['price']) * 2 + 0.00;
            }
        }   

    }


    session_start();

    $_SESSION['timeCost'] = timeCost();

    echo timeCost()." in euros<br /><br />";

    echo "<div class='fauxButton' id='sendInfo'></div>";


} else {
?>

<form method="POST" action="#" name="chooseDateForm" id="chooseDateForm">
            <label>Name:</label>
            <input type="text" value="" name="name" />

            <label>Telephone:</label>
            <input type="text" value="" name="telephone" />

            <label>Email:</label>
            <input type="text" value="" name="myemail" />

            <label>From:</label>
            <select name="from">
                <option selected="selected">Malaga</option>
            </select>
            <div class="clr"></div>

            <label>To:</label>
            <select name="to">

<?php foreach ($data as $place => $price){
    echo "<option>{$place}</option>\n";
}
echo '</select>
            <div class="clr"></div>

            <label>Date:</label>
            <input type="text" value="dd/mm/yyyy" id="date" name="date" class="date-pick" />
            <span id="calendar"></span>

            <div id="return-journey">
                <label>Return Date:</label>
                <input type="text" value="dd/mm/yyyy" id="returndate" name="returndate" class="date-pick" />
                <span id="calendar"></span>
            </div>

            <label>Number of people:</label>
            <select id="people" name="people">
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
            </select>
            <div class="clr"></div>

            <div id="return">
                <label>Is this a return<br />journey?</label>
                <div class="clr"></div>
                <div id="radio-buttons">
                    <input type="radio" name="return" value="Yes" class="radio returning" />Yes<br />
                    <input type="radio" name="return" value="No" class="radio" checked />No
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clr"></div>


            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="fauxButton" />            

        </form>';
}
?>
```

I added this:

```
<div class='fauxButton' id='sendInfo'></div>
```

but as the form has already been sent I cannot change the action in jQuery, I don't know much about jQuery or PHP so if anyone could advise/help please do.

thanks

Comment: Why you can't use this page as 'thank you' one? If post isset and everything validates you can just print out "tahnk you" stuff instead of form. If it does not validate then print out form/errors.

Comment: I agree with @Qmal, It seems like you have an extra step here. What is your purpose in not sending them directly to the thank you page and sending the info to the Admin?

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your button:

```
OnClick="location.href='http://www.YourUrlGoesHere.com'"
//So it will look like this..
echo "<div class='fauxButton' id='sendInfo' OnClick=\"location.href='http://www.YourUrlGoesHere.com'\"></div>"
```